# TF keras layer is no longer saveable?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras, tensorflow-agents

After recent upgrade to Tensorflow 2.3 i cannot save TF-agents layers, i get this:

```
AttributeError: 'ActorDistributionNetwork' object has no attribute 'save_weights'
```

Since `ActorDistributionNetwork` is a subclass of `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, have individual keras layer ability to save themselves been removed? I could not find anything about this in release changes neither for `tensorflow` nor for `tf-agents`.
Using `model.save_weights` is not very convinient for `tf-agents`, since i have to use different combinations of layers for a custom agent.

Comment: Why not inherit from `Model` instead of `Layer`? It's hacky, but it works.

Comment: That would be a question for `tf-agents` developers, but they decided not to do this

Comment: You can always wrap a `Model` around the layer in your code.